# Eclipse Neon 3 problems with PyDev not being recognized after install

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have Neon.3 Release (4.6.3) installed on my Mac (Sierra 10.12.4) and I installed PyDev 5.7. When I open a Python program there is no highlighting. If I go to a new project Python is not an option. Here is what is showing as installed:

PyDev for Eclipse 5.7.0.201704111357  org.python.pydev.feature.feature.group  Fabio Zadrozny
  PyDev for Eclipse Developer Resources 5.7.0.201704111357  org.python.pydev.feature.source.feature.group   Fabio Zadrozny

Comment: I have the exact same problem - even after following all instructions at the getting started page at http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_install.html. My environment is:

* java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

* eclipse
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500

* PyDev 5.7.0.zip

Comment: I can't really reproduce this... have you followed the getting started guide: http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_root.html ? If everything fails, you can try to get the latest LiClipse, which has PyDev builtin: http://www.liclipse.com (it's eclipse neon 3 + pydev and some other goodies -- although it's commercial).